# SaveAs producing Incompatible filetype and extension errors (Runtime error 6294)

Tags: vba, ms-word, save

I have a tool that I modified from elsewhere on the web to work with current 2021 MS Word Visual Basic for applications (v7.1).   It's basically a batch password removal tool for Word documents.

This code simply goes through a directory opening all the files, assumign they have the same password, and then saves them out to a second directory with the passwords removed.

However it fails on the `SaveAs` line, with

> runtime error 6294.

```
Dim myFile As String
Dim PathToUse As String
Dim myDoc As Document
Dim strPassword As String

strPassword = "current_password"
PathToUse = "C:\source"
SavePath = "C:\destination\"

myFile = Dir$(PathToUse & "*.docx")
While myFile <> ""
    'Open document
    Set myDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=PathToUse & myFile, PasswordDocument:=strPassword)
  
    myDoc.SaveAs SavePath & myFile, Password = ""
    myDoc.Close
    'Next file in folder
    myFile = Dir$()
Wend
```

Comment: Please, try `myDoc.SaveAs FileName:=SavePath & myFile, Password:=""`

Comment: `PathToUse` is missing the backslash at the end. You have one at the end of `SavePath`.

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru that was it! Feel free to write an answer if you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try

```
myDoc.SaveAs FileName:=SavePath & myFile, Password:=""
```

The `SaveAs` method needs parameters. Some of them are `Optional`, but if you need some, they must be used in the above suggested way.